# Configuring Mercurial's built-in server

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I'm trying to get an install of Mercurial setup at work to evaluate it with our legacy code.  The "server" I'm currently using is simply a desktop running Windows XP with SP3 on our intranet.  The "client" install is on my local desktop, also running Windows XP with SP3.  (I'm also using TortoiseHG on both machines.)

The web server is running at `http://localhost:8000`, and I can view the repository in a browser.  But, when I try to  detect outgoing changes to the repo, I get an HTTP 404 error.  I can see the request show up in the server's log, so I'm pointing to the right location, but it shows `GET http://host:8000/reponame?cmd=capabilities HTTP/1.1 404`.  No matter what settings I change, I can't seem to get the client to successfully execute a command against the repo.  Does anyone have an idea why this wouldn't be working?

Comment: Are you trying to push to your own repository?  Or you have two repositories? I think you might be confused.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup, and I had similar problems.

I use the following command to run my HG serve (it's in a batch file):

```
hg.exe serve --prefix mercurial --address 123.12.1.1 --port 8008 --web-conf hg-web.conf --accesslog hg-access.log --errorlog hg-error.log
```

In the hg-web.conf I have:

```
[web]
style = default
allow_push = *
push_ssl = false

[paths]
my-repo = c:\hg\my-repo
```

With this setup, I can access my repository by accessing url `http://ip:port/mercurial/my-repo`

I can push without a problem.

Try this setup and I hope it helps you resolve your problem.

Comment: So, you run the batch file for your HG Serve, and then it's up and running?

Answer (score 0):

Well, when I start internal server in my TortoiseHG (for single repo, `Repostory` - `Start Web-server` from Workbench main menu)

- Server window tells 'Running on localhost:8000', but really server listens on all interfaces (`netstat -na` shows `TCP    0.0.0.0:8000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING`)
- On clone-edit-commit in fork and testing outgoing (from THG directly) I see

`% hg --repository Z:\clone outgoing http://10.1.14.94:8000/`

`comparing with http://10.1.14.94:8000/`

`searching for changes`

`changeset:   39:c57a9357ec55`

`tag:         tip`

`user:        I`

`date:        Fri Mar 08 17:00:05 2013 +0600`

`summary:     Test-change`

Some times ago I also pulled|pushed from|to these Mercurial repos from my another host. Server config is trivial and all was done inside TortoiseHG settings.

My [web] section in mercurial.ini (and nothing more)

```
[web]
port = 8000
encoding = UTF-8
allow_archive = bz2, gz, zip
style = gitweb
```

(push disabled now, work in pull-only mode)

PS: TortoiseHg version 2.7.1 on Windows XP SP3

Answer (score 0):

Push means to move a changeset from one repo to another. You haven't stated that you made two separate clones of the repo, then try to push from A to B. So let's assume you're confused here, and talk about that confusion: Imagine I try to push from my own repo to an hg serve instance running against my own repo. That's like trying to phone myself to tell myself something.

Secondly, if you're really trying to push from A to B, and there really are changes in A that need to get to B, then, your actual problem is probably that you haven't got the URL of the repository input correctly into your GUI tool, which is Tortoise HG, I assume.  Try it again from the command line while you're learning. If you get an error post the error here: `hg push http://myserver:8000`

The first time I tried Mercurial, after a long history of using Subversion, I had come to think I needed a "server" component more than I actually did.  In subversion the server is where commits happen.  IN mercurial, commits happen locally, and when you push to the remote (perhaps central) server, then the other people on your team see your changes.  This is the big difference. I asssume you're trying to push, because commits happen locally.  If you're confused about the difference between a commit and a push, then I suggest you look at http://hginit.com/

As far as setting up a server, there are three fairly easy options I can recommend:

1. "hg serve" from the commandline, as shown by other answers.  Easy, and for temporary use only. Perfect for learning.
2. Install Mercurial inside Apache (easier than installing Mercurial inside IIS) for a permanent web-server with full authentication and perhaps encryption.    If you use [hgwebdir](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep) instructions on the Mercurial wiki it should take you about an hour. If you use the pre-built solutions, it should take much less time.  I used Bitnami's pre-built solutions for windows and got one up in 5 minutes recently. Bitnami makes available installers that will get python, apache, mercurial, and other stuff, all installed and working together in what they call a "stack" (bunch o stuff that already works).
3. Here's the really brilliant solution.  Use the free private web repositories at BitBucket.org. Free for public (open source) and private (small teams and personal) use, and quite cheap for large teams. Admin effort for you? No more than logging into a website. And you're done.

Comment: The hg serve instance is running on a separate machine, so my assumption was that it would be treated as the remote repository.  The code has already been committed to my local repository, and all I'm trying to do is get that initial changeset pushed to the remote repo so I can pull it down to a different machine.  When I try hg push http://myserver:8000, I get "HTTP Error 406: Not Acceptable".

Comment: That's what the guy above me put down about editing hgweb.conf